# Method with parameter or return value - Javascript

Tags: javascript, class, parameters, return-value

I'm confused about how I can edit my code so that I can have at least one method that uses a parameter (or return values) rather than just console.log. I'd appreciate any help or suggestions you guys can provide thank you! :) Here's my code:

```
class Planet{
  constructor(name, numberOfMoons, size) {
    this.name = name;
    this.numberOfMoons = numberOfMoons;
    this.size = size;
  }
  orbit(){
    console.log(this.name + ' is a planet and therefore orbits around the sun.');
  }
}

//inheritance class

 class DwarfPlanet extends Planet{
  constructor(name, numberOfMoons, size, orbitalNeighbourhood) {
    super(name, numberOfMoons, size);
    this.orbital = orbitalNeighbourhood;
  }

  getOrbital(){
    console.log(this.name + " is a dwarf planet because it doesn't have a clear orbital neighnourhood ");
  }

}

let earth = new Planet('Earth', 1 , 6371);
earth.orbit();

let pluto = new DwarfPlanet("Pluto", 5 , 1188, 'Kuiper Belt');
pluto.getOrbital();

//Array of Objects
var stars = [
    {
        name: 'Sun',
        temperature: 5778,
        colour: 'White'
    },
    {
        name: 'Pistol',
        temperature: 11800,
        colour: 'Blue'
    },
    {
        name: "Antares",
        temperature: 3500,
        colour: "Red"
    }
];
console.log("Fun Fact: the biggest star isn't the sun, instead it is a blue star called 'Pistol'. Here's some information about it: ");
console.log(stars[1]);
```

Comment: Replace `console.log()` with `return` followed by whatever value you wish to return as in `return this.name + ' is a planet and therefore orbits around the sun.';`

Comment: ohh okay thank you! so much! Are there any other ways like adding new data or something?

Comment: Also know that a "parameter" and a "return value" are two very different things. "Parameters" are what's passed into a function and are then used as local variables throughout the function's processing. A "return value" is any value you would like the function to return to the caller.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.. Any other ways to return data? The only other way would be for the function to reassign a value of a variable that has a higher scope than the function.

Comment: how would you suggest I have a method that utilizes a parameter then?

Comment: You are already doing that with your class constructors, for example `constructor(name, numberOfMoons, size)`. `name`, `numberOfMoons`, and `size` are the parameters that are to be passed to the constructor when it's called as in: `let myPlanet= new Planet("Earth", 1, "big");`. "Earth", 1, "big" become the values stored in the `name`, `numberOfMoons`, and `size` parameters.

Comment: You should learn about functions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions).

Comment: ok thank you so much!

Comment: @ScottMarcus sorry I just tried out the first code you gave me where you said just replace console.log w the return value it didn't work? nothing printed out?

Comment: It's working just fine. Nothing printed out because `console.log` is what makes things print out and you removed that. `return` just sends the value back to the caller of the code. It's then up to the caller of the code to decide what to do with that data.

Answer (score 0):

So what everyone has been saying is correct, but I just want to sum a few things up.

You have to actually return a value from a method for it to have a value. Then you can `console.log` that value that is returned. You can do both if you want.

For methods you can pass parameters in any way. For example

```js
const func = (param1, param2) => {
  return `This is Param 1: ${param1}  This is Param 2: ${param2}`
} // This function returns a String

console.log(func("Hi", "Hello"));
```

So for what your doing with the classes you would simply just pass in a parameter into the method like any other normal function. I updated your code sample to include how you could do this with the stars array.

I also updated the instance methods with out to get them to return an actual value.

If I were you I would review something like this W3 article: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp

Also this MDN article on classes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Just to get the fundamentals down.

Good Luck

```js
class Planet{
    constructor(name, numberOfMoons, size) {
        this.name = name;
        this.numberOfMoons = numberOfMoons;
        this.size = size;
    }
    orbit(){
        return `${this.name} is a planet and therefore orbits around the sun.`
    }
}

//inheritance class

class DwarfPlanet extends Planet{
    constructor(name, numberOfMoons, size, orbitalNeighbourhood) {
        super(name, numberOfMoons, size);
        this.orbital = orbitalNeighbourhood;
    }

    getOrbital(){
        return `${this.name} is a dwarf planet because it doesn't have a clear orbital neighnourhood "`
    }

}

let earth = new Planet('Earth', 1 , 6371);
console.log(earth.orbit());

let pluto = new DwarfPlanet("Pluto", 5 , 1188, 'Kuiper Belt');
console.log(pluto.getOrbital());

class Stars {
    constructor() {
        this.stars = [];
    }

    addStars(star){
        this.stars.push(star);
    }

    addMultipleStars(stars){
        this.stars = [...this.stars, ...stars]
    }

    allStars(){
        return this.stars;
    }
}
//Array of Objects
var stars = [
    {
        name: 'Sun',
        temperature: 5778,
        colour: 'White'
    },
    {
        name: 'Pistol',
        temperature: 11800,
        colour: 'Blue'
    },
    {
        name: "Antares",
        temperature: 3500,
        colour: "Red"
    }
];

let startContainer = new Stars();
startContainer.addMultipleStars(stars);
const allStars = startContainer.allStars();
allStars.forEach(star => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(star))
})
```

Comment: thank you for that I really appreciate that but I haven't gone over anything related to JSON. Is there another way I can execute what you just did maybe with reading or writing different files?

Comment: also, is the code compatible with Node because I just tried the first part and it didn't work?

Comment: Yeah its compatible with node, which part broke? Also the data types of stars are JSON objects.   {
        name: "Antares",
        temperature: 3500,
        colour: "Red"
    }
That is JSON. Also it seems to run fine in the above editor.

Comment: In terms of files are you asking how to read files in Node.js?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and stay as far away from W3 Schools as you can. It's well known to have incomplete, outdated, or flat out incorrect information. Stick with MDN.